# Open sets' properties in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology

This question comes from my intuition and I think the following statement is correct. However I cannot figure out the proof:

Let $A$ be an non empty open set in $\mathbb R^n$ where $x$ is in $A$. Also let 
$$R=\sup_{r>0}\{r:B_r(x)\subseteq A\}$$

The set $\{r>0:B_r(x)\subseteq A\}$ is nonempty since $x$ is an interior point of $A$.

Then isn't that $B_R(x)\subseteq A$ ?

If it is not true, can anyone give me a counter-example please?

Comment: $B_r(x)$ denotes the _open_ ball of radius $r$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true. For every $y\in B_R(x)$ you have $|x-y|<R$. Now there must be an $s>|x-y|$ such that $B_s(x)\subseteq A$ (because if there wasn't, $R$ couldn't be the *least* upper bound for such $s$s). But then by definition $y\in B_s(x)\subseteq A$. Since $y$ was arbitrary, $B_R(x)$ is a subset of $A$.

Answer (score 3):

It is true.

Suppose $y \in B_R(x)$. Then $\lVert x-y \rVert < R$, so there exists $0 < s < R$ such that $\lVert x-y \rVert < s$... say $s = \frac{\lVert x-y \rVert + R}{2}$ or something. But $R$ is the supremum of all the $r > 0$ such that $B_r(x) \subseteq X$. Since $s<R$ we must have $B_s(x) \subseteq A$, and hence $y \in A$.

Comment: It seems to require some argument that $s=\frac{\|x-y\|+R}{2}$ _in particular_ satisfies $B_s(x)\subseteq A$ ... such as arguing that the set we're taking supremum over is downwards closed.